# Appending to array in closure

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im pulling userUID data from my firebase database and putting it into an array. When I go to print the array outside of the observe closure it doesn't print, but inside of the closure it does. Whats happening here?

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var userUIDArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRef.child("Users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for child in snapshots {
            self.userUIDArray.append(child.key)
        }
    })
    print(self.userUIDArray)
}
```

Comment: The closure is running asynchronously.  Your final print is happening before the closure has had a chance to append the values to your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the closure is executed asynchronously (after a network request is made), which means it executes after the rest of the code inside of `viewDidLoad`.

Here is a quick ordering of when the code is executed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // #1

    databaseRef.child("Users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // #3
    })

    // #2

}
```

The `print` statement outside of the closure prints nothing because there are no elements in the array when it is called. The `print` statement inside the closure works because the array has been modified before it is called.

Here is an example of how to use this data when it is returned from Firebase:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var userUIDArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRef.child("Users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for child in snapshots {
            self.userUIDArray.append(child.key)
        }
        updateUserInterface()
    })

}

func updateUserInterface() {
    // update the UI here using the `userUIDArray` variable
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How would I go about getting them appended in my array?

Comment: You are appending them in your array correctly. If you want to use the data (to update the UI for example), you could call a function from inside the closure (marked #3) instead of in viewDidLoad (marked #2).

Comment: Do you mind showing me what that looks like. I tried it but I must have done it wrong.

Comment: Yea I still can't get it. I really don't know what to put in the function to update the tableview.

Comment: You should be able to call `reloadData` on the table view.

Comment: Great! If you could mark my answer as accepted, it will help others in the future who have the same issue.